# Failed to access IIS metabase

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am having too much trouble with this IIS.
First it was giving me an error Virtual directory denied.

I realized there was no default.aspx in the documents tab.. (it has default.asp, default.htm, iistart, index.htm). Checked that liitle box enable default documents

Now it says Failed to access IIS metabase
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentException: Failed to access IIS metabase

This is the first time working on IIS.. So I need ur hints and fixes

Thanks
SC

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to install the .net framework on you system

Open visual studio command prompt and type this command

```
aspnet_regiis -ga <UserName>
```

if this doesn'twork than use this command

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

alternatively you can copy and paste this command into windows command prompt

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

this will fix your problem

Comment: @Pranay: Should it be version 2.0 or 4.0

Comment: @Pranay:I used this aspnet_regiis -ga<username> and it said Granting user access to IIS metabase and other directories...

Comment: @user575219 - and select property framwork by clicking on virtual directory>> property >> set the framework..........this framwork is the frawmework in which you developed your website

Comment: But now it says Failed to access IIS metabase.. Does it have anything to do with Virtual directory path

Comment: Yes in my Properties, i have 2.0 and 4.0. But i selected 2.0. so here in this command I used the v2.0

Comment: .net framework is already installed.. Dosent it come with Visual web developer 2010

Comment: This worked for me. Had to do it using the aspnet_regiis in the 4.x directory.

Comment: It worked for me. %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i